What does it mean in TypeScript when a value of an object has a type "never"?
In TypeScript, how would the type {a: number, b: never} manifest an actual object?
Does the key b not exist? Can the value for it not be assigned?
I don't see a way of constructing a conforming object other than hacking in the type for b's value like {a: 12, b: null as never}
EDIT: A use case. Consider a function that consumes an object with string keys and array values, and returns an object with the keys that have a non-empty array value, with the value of the first item in the array.
function Foo<
  T extends { [key: string]: any[] },
  U extends { [K in keyof T]: T[K][number] }
>(
  obj: T
): U {
  const result = {} as U;

  for (const key in obj) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[key]) && obj[key].length > 0) {
      result[key] = obj[key][0];
    }
  }

  return result;
}

const myObj = {
  a: [1, 2],
  b: []
};

const result = Foo(myObj);

const expected = {
  a: 1
};

Here result has the type {a:number, b:never} but the actual expected type is {a: number}. I don't see a way to produce a reference expected object for unit testing, or to accurately describe the output type in the function generics section.

Pragmatically no such value exists. Technically you can write const x = {a: 12, get b(): never {throw new Error()}} but nobody does that. TypeScript doesn't always aggressively reduce types to never even if they are essentially equivalent. So, uh, why are you asking this question? What situation caused something like this to come up? Knowing the use case or origin of the question might help us give an answer that actually explains something for you.

Okay, that edit is just highlighting that without --noUncheckedIndexedAccesses you'll sometimes have situations where undefined is left out. Surely [][0] is undefined, but TS will say never unless you make TS stricter about index signatures. The use case has definitely cleared up the point of the question. Could you [edit] so that the use case is in the question more directly? Like, "why does const x = [][0] give never instead of undefined?"

Have you read the documentation of never? It does not explain all its usages but it is a good starting point understanding how it works.

You can't create a conforming object without type assertions or similar shenanigans.  Given that your desired expected value omits the key for the null type, there is a way you can use that value.
You can create a generic mapped type declaration to remove all the properties typed as never.  This is done using as in the mapped type declaration.
type NonNever<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends never ? never : K]: T[K]
};

Then use it like this.
type Test = {a: number, b: never};
const t: NonNever<Test> = { a: 3 };


I'm not sure how this answer applies to the question. Can you [edit] to articulate exactly how it relates?

I added a few sentences explaining how the type pertains to the given code example.
